# Google Calendar API returning 403 Rate Limit Exceeded within a single batch request

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, batch-processing

My application creates and deletes Google Calendar events on behalf of users. Each user authorizes through the OAuth portal and that user's `access_token` is used to access the API, rather than a service account.

I was having issues with various rate-limit errors, and so I started to batch requests. But despite batching requests, many of the requests within the batch fail. It is only me testing this locally -- there are no other users on the service.

For example, you can see below that several of the `delete`s in the batch request failed (numbers 2, 6, 7, 8, etc.). This batch request with ~a dozen `delete` requests was the only thing sent in the previous several minutes, and there had been probably 6 batch requests in the previous hour (many with the same issue).

If I then fired off another batch request immediately after, I would see the same pattern: several of the sub-requests succeeding and others failing. This leads me to believe that I haven't gone over any sort of global / day-based limit, but rather that there's something broken in the batch request itself.

```
[2020-08-03 13:55:03,101: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Error with batch delete request "1": <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/X.com_X%40group.calendar.google.com/events/X? returned "Rate Limit Exceeded">
[2020-08-03 13:55:03,102: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Error with batch delete request "3": <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/X.com_X%40group.calendar.google.com/events/X? returned "Rate Limit Exceeded">
[2020-08-03 13:55:03,102: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Error with batch delete request "4": <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/X.com_X%40group.calendar.google.com/events/X? returned "Rate Limit Exceeded">
[2020-08-03 13:55:03,103: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Error with batch delete request "5": <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/X.com_X%40group.calendar.google.com/events/X? returned "Rate Limit Exceeded">
[2020-08-03 13:55:03,103: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Error with batch delete request "6": <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/X.com_X%40group.calendar.google.com/events/X? returned "Rate Limit Exceeded">
[2020-08-03 13:55:03,103: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Error with batch delete request "9": <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/X.com_X%40group.calendar.google.com/events/X? returned "Rate Limit Exceeded">
[2020-08-03 13:55:03,103: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Error with batch delete request "10": <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/X.com_X%40group.calendar.google.com/events/X? returned "Rate Limit Exceeded">
```

(the `X`s are my redaction of personal info)

To the extent it's helpful, here's the very basic code causing this:

```
batch = c.new_batch_http_request(callback=batch_delete_callback)
for event in events:
    if event is not None:
        r = c.events().delete(calendarId=gcal_id, eventId=event)
        batch.add(r)
batch.execute()
```

And the callback:

```
def batch_delete_callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        print('Error with batch delete request "{0}": {1}'.format(
            request_id, exception))
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I best handle or avoid these 403s from Google?

**Update**

I just tried to minimally test this, to get the immediate failure case. I ran a batch request that added 12 events to my calendar, and then ran a batch request that attempted to delete those same 12 events roughly 15 seconds later. So just 2 batch requests with 12 sub-requests in each. And this is after no action whatsoever for 20 hours since I last tried.

And of the 12 `delete` requests, 8 of them failed. So I had 12 `create` requests succeed, and then 8/12 `delete` requests returned a `403 Rate Limit Exceeded`

As noted in my comments below, my console shows quotas of 1,000,000 queries per day and 100,000,000 queries per 100 seconds per user. So I just can't tell what limit I'm hitting.

Answer (score 0):

### Batching decreases you total number of requests, but the rate limit still applies

- Actually, when batching, your code executes faster and you are more likely to run into rate limit issues.
- You need to slow down your code execution or request in the developer console an increase of quota.

**The following procedures arerecommended in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#403_user_rate_limit_exceeded) to avoid  `403 Rate Limit Exceeded` errors:**

> Suggested actions:
>
> - Raise the per-user quota in the Developer Console project.
> - If one user is making a lot of requests on behalf of many users of a G Suite domain, consider a Service Account with authority delegation (setting the quotaUser parameter).
> - Use exponential backoff.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately I cannot tell what rate limit I am hitting. Right now I see in the console that I have limits of 1,000,000 queries per day and 100,000,000 queries per 100 seconds per user. But I'm getting these errors even by doing 2 batch requests with ~a dozen requests in each of them. In order words: not event remotely close to those rate limits!

Comment: I suppose I could exponentially back off each individual request, but that would mean that I just can't use batch requests at all, since I can't see a way to back off a sub-request within a batch request. But again, it seems bizarre to me that this is happening at the scale of doing a couple dozen requests in the space of a few minutes here...

Comment: I just updated the original post at the bottom with a more minimal test of this. Thanks again for looking at this.

Comment: Did you test if you can avoid the error by using exponential back off without batch requests? Are you using a service account? are you only performing delete requests or also others? It might take some time until your quota are reset. If nothing helps - as a GSuite customer you can contact [support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en&ref_topic=7067151) and try to find out which is the exact quota you hit.

Comment: @AndyBromberg having the exact same issue as you. Have you gotten any further with it?

Comment: Google Support is indicating it may be a known issue. They've recommended a few troubleshooting steps -- including trying a service account with domain-wide delegation instead of normal OAuth access. Their latest suggestion is that it might be because my domain doesn't have a lot of user accounts and such domains are sometimes rate limited. So they've asked me to add 5 more user accounts to my domain, which I haven't tried yet. They've also noted that it is unusual that only DELETE calls are failing and not anything else.

Comment: @AndyBromberg I am experience the same thing. Our app create/update/cancel calendar event and 67% of the DELETE actions failed but none of the create/update action failed. Sound strange right? Do you have the link to where Google support talk about this issue and give the suggestions? Thanks in advance.